# noSuchElement exception with nextInt() method

Tags: eclipse, exception, java.util.scanner

Hey guys I don't get why I get an exception in this simple code
I'm trying to make a card game, and try to read the users wanted index of the card in his hand (it's in German)

```
public Karte abschlagen(Karte gegnK) {
    System.out
            .println("Bitte die Zahl für die jeweilige Karte auswählen: ");
    gibHandAus(); // prints the users cards with their indexes 

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index = sc.nextInt();
        if (index < 0 || index >= getHand().size()) {
            System.out
                    .println("Bitte nur eine der gegebenen Zahlen auswählen!");
                     sc.close();
            return abschlagen(gegnK);
        }
        Karte k = getHand().get(index);
        getHand().remove(index);
        sc.close();
```

So what's the problem here?
Before I can choose a number, it throws the noSuchElement exception.
I read in another question that the close() method can be causing this, but it still did it without it.

The error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) 
   at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) 
   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) 
   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) 
   at durak.Spiel.spielerWehrtAb(Spiel.java:229) 
   at durak.Spiel.main(Spiel.java:314)
```

EDIT: Code of spielerWehrAb():

```
public static boolean spielerWehrtAb(Karte k) {
.
.
.
try {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = sc.nextInt();
sc.close();

if (x == 0) {
... }
else if(x == 1) {
System.out.println("1 ausgewählt");
Karte k2 = spieler.abschlagen(k);
....
} 
else return spielerWehrAb(k);
```

Comment: can you put the printstacktrace output here?

Comment: @Reza
the error message is 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at durak.Spiel.spielerWehrtAb(Spiel.java:229)
 at durak.Spiel.main(Spiel.java:314)


     Whoa sorry i Dont know how to add linebreaks in comments

Comment: The exception is happening inside `spielerWehrtAb` method!

Comment: @Reza Yes, in this method it calls the method I posted, and it the error comes up, just after the method `gibHandAus()`printed out all cards

Comment: `main -> spielerWehrtAb -> abschlagen -> nextInt`
why is `abschlagen`  missing in the stack trace? Strange!

Comment: @Reza wait you are right....I just didnt think the error would be there, since the Scanner and nextInt() there worked fine and let me choose a number (0 or 1 for taking cards or putting some), and when I chose 1, it shows the cards with indexes (`gibHandAus()`) and then crashes ||  But what is the problem now, wait I'll post the other code fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Scanner.close();` closes the underlying stream. The second time, you're trying to read from a closed stream, so it obviously fails.

Please see the tests I designed to demonstrate this behavior here:  [java.util.Scanner strange behaviour when used with System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410327/java-util-scanner-strange-behaviour-when-used-with-system-in/)

The solution would be not to read after closing the `Scanner`. You could, for example, define the `Scanner` as a class member and always use that member.

Comment: Ok I will try that and tell you later if it worked, thank you

Comment: Wow thank you it finally worked that way! 
You're the best^^
---I would upvote you but I need more reputation for that :P