# java.util.Scanner strange behaviour when used with System.in

Tags: java, system.in

This simple piece of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = sc1.nextInt();
        sc1.close();

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number2 = sc2.nextInt();
        sc2.close();
    }

}
```

always gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at mainpkg.TestScanner.main(TestScanner.java:14)
```

This one doesn't work either. This time it falls into a never-ending loop!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = sc1.nextInt();
        sc1.close();

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!sc2.hasNextInt())
            ;
        int number2 = sc2.nextInt();
        sc2.close();
    }

}
```

Why?

Comment: I hope there was some good reason for giving down votes to this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `sc1.close();` closes the underlying stream. The second time, you're trying to read from a closed stream, so it obviously fails.

Comment: Does it mean after the `Scanner` is closed, it couldn't be used again or is there any solution on this?

Comment: @Reza err... don't close the scanner?

Comment: I think once System.in gets closed, you can't use it anymore. The solution is to use only one Scanner.

Comment: @aditsu I agree with you.

Comment: @Doorknob yeah. I think the Scanner mustn't be closed.

Comment: @Reza: Indeed.  But you also need to handle the case where there is no more input, so you will still need to use `hasNextInt`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Agreed.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth in the case of System.in, hasNextInt actually waits for more input, then checks whether the input looks like an int. "No more input" can happen only if the user sends an EOF character (ctrl-d in linux, possibly ctrl-z in windows) or if the input is redirected from a file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking each time with `hasNextInt`, rather than just assuming that there's more to read.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Could you put a working code here, please?

Comment: @Reza: I'm not going to write your code for you.  I suggest referring to a book on Java, or perhaps a tutorial, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html.

Comment: There is no mentioning of such a problem there. This is why I asked it here. `hasNextInt` cannot solve the issue (I couldn't. Please see the update)

Comment: @Reza: There's a working example of how to use `hasNext` and `next`.  You should use that pattern.